Not able to Change version of Solidity Compiler from 0.7.3 to 0.8.25 VS Code
I am getting following error while Compiling my Solidity Program.
Compiling using solidity from node_modules, solidity version: 0.7.3+commit.9bfce1f6.Emscripten.clang
c:/Users/ADMIN/aave-flash-loan-tutorial/aave-flash-loan-v3/contracts/FlashLoan.sol:1:1: ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.7.3+commit.9bfce1f6.Emscripten.clang) - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
pragma solidity 0.8.25;
I tried to change the Compiler version from 0.7.3 to 0.8.25 by
1.Default Compiler - Remote
2.Compile using Remote Version - Settings.json
{
"solidity.compileUsingLocalVersion": "",
"solidity.compileUsingRemoteVersion": "0.8.25+commit.b61c2a91.Emscripten.clang"
}
But my Compiler Version is not changed.
thanks
Uday

Are you using hardhat? If yes, then change the version in hardhat config file,

According to my knowledge assuming you are using VS code and have the official solidity extension maintained by Juan Blanco (found here). The extension is official in the sense that it is the only extension recommended by ethereum.org.
The extension provides a very easy way of toggling compilers:

In any *.sol file, right click and press "change workspace compiler
version (Remote)"

Choose your compiler.

Set the compiler version accordingly in config.js if you are using hardhat and then also change on the top of smart contract.


Thats it.


I set as above.

Sure @Udayarajangauthaman
